# Text selection CTRL+SHIFT+Cursor Keys?

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys

I'm used to this Windows behavior that using <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+Cursor Keys</kbd> I can select text word-wise. <kbd>CTRL+Cursor Keys</kbd> jumps word-wise and I use that a lot in combination with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to select text.

This seems to be a "Windows thing" because it just works in all application. Now turning to Ubuntu 10.04, it doesn't work. <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+Cursor Keys</kbd> just behaves like <kbd>CTRL+Cursor Keys</kbd>, i.e. I jump between the *words* but I can't select them that way.

Another gotcha: I use <kbd>CTRL+Cursor Keys</kbd> to move fast between words, press down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and move the <kbd>Cursor Keys</kbd> to select text char by char and it doesn't work either. I need to release both keys complete.

Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're having this problem - Ctrl+Shift+Left/Right cursor jumps text and highlights. What programs are you experiencing this issue in?

Comment: In every application I tried. Notably Firefox and Eclipse. Now I'm wondering what's going on here ...

Comment: Could you include what your current keyboard layout is? System -> Preferences -> Keyboard

Comment: Text selection using Ctrl+Shift+<CursorKey> has always worked for me in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem: in Windows I use multiple keyboard layouts and I use <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT</kbd> to switch between them. I configured the same for Ubuntu however I'm experiencing a clash here obviously.

That said, Windows is smarty enough to figure out by analyzing which keys I press over time what I want. Ubuntu isn't: once I pressed <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT</kbd>, not matter what additional keys, it switched the keyboard layout and for some reason this interrupted the selection option. Too bad.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem. Discovered that it's 11 years old bug in XOrg.

Here is Ubuntu's bug discussion started in 2006:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/36812

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Firefox/Chrome/gEdit.  Maddening!  This fixed it:

System -> Keyboard Input Methods -> Layouts tab -> Options... -> Misc. compat. options -> Shift w/ numeric keypad keys works as in MS Windows

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome / Firefox, if you select text starting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to highlight at least one block, then you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to select by word.